# Javascript - One array contains another

Tags: javascript

If i have two arrays like so:

```
var array1 = ['this', 'is', 'array', '1']
var array2 = ['this', 'is', '1']
```

Is there a built in function that can determine if array1 contains array2.  Which in this case it does.

Alternatively some intersect function or similar?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript for discussion re: array intersect

Comment: Do you want an efficient solution, or a short (easy to read) one? And will they always contain strings?

Comment: Short and easy to read is fine as its dealing with very small arrays.  They will always be strings yeah.

Answer (score 0):

try this with underscore (library based on javascript)  http://underscorejs.org/

```
_.every(array1, function(e){ return _.include(array2, e)}); //=> false
_.every(array2, function(e){ return _.include(array1, e)}); //=> true
```

Comment: Oh, so like `array2.every(function (e) { return array1.indexOf(e) !== -1; });`?

Comment: Doesn't Underscore have an intersection function built in?

Comment: Yes it does have, as Lodash